# invalid arithmetic operator - when running check

Tags: curl, integer, operator-keyword

I am trying to evaluate the return from runningg a curl check.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
length=$(curl -s -I www.google.com | grep Length | awk {'print $2'})
if [[ $length -le 300 ]]
        then
                echo "length is too small"
fi
```

the output is 258:

```
mira:~ david$ curl -s -I www.google.com | grep Length | awk {'print $2'}  
258
```

so I would like to run the echo command since its smaller than 300.

I get error:

> mira:~ david$ ./test.sh  ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator
>   (error token is " mira:~ david$

many thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a return carriage `\r` which comes from curl:

```
 bash -x test.sh 
++ grep Length
++ curl -s -I www.google.com
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ length=$'258\r'
+ '[' $'258\r' -le 300 ']'
: integer expression expected
```

you can fix that by using printf instead of print on awk:

```
#!/bin/bash
length=$(curl -s -I www.google.com | grep Length | awk '{printf "%d",$2}')
if [[ "$length" -le 300 ]]
        then
                echo "length is too small"
fi
```

Result:

```
tiago@dell:~$ bash test.sh 
length is too small
tiago@dell:~$ bash -x test.sh 
++ grep Length
++ curl -s -I www.google.com
++ awk '{printf "%d",$2}'
+ length=258
+ [[ 258 -le 300 ]]
+ echo 'length is too small'
length is too small
```

PS. `bash -x` is very helpful for debugging shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks - I was going bald pulling my hair out !